# CSS hidden text illegal for Search Engines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hidden

Here are basic example boxes, CSS and JS I created for jQuery Modal Box.

```
<!-- hidden boxes // -->
<div id="content_1" class="box">
    <h1>First Box</h1>
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
</div>
<div id="content_2" class="box">
    <h1>Second Box</h1>
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
</div>
.....

<!-- links for boxes // -->
<a href="#content_1" class="link">Show First Box</a>
<a href="#content_2" class="link">Show Second Box</a>

<!-- css // -->
<style>
.box {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<!-- javascript // -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.link').click( function() {
        // process modal
    });
});
</script>
```

So when User click on First/Second Box link, the jQuery modal popup with content. My Purpose is not to hide the text. I heard and read in some blogs, Google will take action with hidden text. Is my way illegal/bad for SEO? OR are there better way to do this without `display:none`?

Comment: yes, use `text-indent:-9999px;`

Comment: Wait, there is at least one Google employee who [states](http://maileohye.com/html-text-indent-not-messing-up-your-rankings/) that `text-indent` triggers their spam filter. So, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I can't believe search engines would be dumb enough to fall for the `text-indent` trick if they penalize for hidden content.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Isn't it a bit problematic for google to flag sites for using `text-indent:-9999px;`. I think there are a lot of them out there which use it as a workaround for a variety of problems.

Comment: @Marcel, apparently page rank computation disregards that it can be a workaround (and even that it can be for accessibility reasons, according to Maile Ohye's article). You would have to ask Google for specific details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find Google themselves actually use `display:none;` on their homepage - and considering the popularity of jQuery and other JavaScript libraries using these kinds of effects, I can't see how it will negatively impact your SEO if you use it in necessary circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I use following snippet to hide sub-menus on css3 navigation menus with some cool ease-in, ease-in-out transitions . And afaik this is valid css to hide elements when it comes to SEO.

```
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
```

Already discussed at
[Is there an alternative to conditional display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141775/is-there-an-alternative-to-conditional-displaynone)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using display:none; you can use left: -9999px;position:absolute;  it will still display the content for the search engine but it will be displayed somewhere not for the users.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/accessibilityseo-friendly-css-hiding/